# Has the XML-Document-Transform xmlns URL changed?

Tags: asp.net, web.config-transform, xml-document-transform, web-debug-config, web-release-config

In your **Web.Release.config** or **Web.Debug.config**, right after ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

you see ...

```xml
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
```

When I browse to this URL, I receive the following content:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Does that mean there's a new URL and I need to update the **`xmlns`** or can you just not browse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an XML namespace, not the location of a resource on the web.

It only happens to look like a URL. Some XML namespaces do not look like URLs.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the enlightenment, you'd think I'd know that by now.  I guess I've never tried to actually browse one until now.